# Can I create an array of functions in Powershell?

Tags: arrays, function, powershell

I would like to have an array that contains a set of functions that I can iterate through and call. The issue is that the functions all run via the line that adds them to the array (ie. $scripts).

Example:

```
function Hello
{
    $BadFunction = "Hello"
    Write-Host "Hello!"
}

function HowAreYou
{
    $BadFunction = "HowAreYou"
    Write-Host "How are you?"
    #$false = $true
}

function Goodbye
{
    $BadFunction = "Goodbye"
    Write-Host "Goodbye!"
}

$scripts = @((Hello), (HowAreYou), (Goodbye))

foreach ($script in $scripts)
{
    $script
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Functions can only be called by using their name, not referenced, but you can get the scriptblock via the `Function:` drive:

```
$scripts = $Function:Hello, $Function:HowAreYou, $Function:GoodBye

# call them with the & operator
$scripts | ForEach-Object { & $_ }

# You can also call them by calling Invoke on the scriptblock
$scripts | ForEach-Object Invoke
```

Comment: You can also use `get-command Hello` instead of `$function:Hello`

Comment: @MikeShepard Those do two very different things.  You may be thinking of `Get-Item -Path Function:\Hello`

Comment: While it's true that they are different things, they both can be executed via the & operator (and can be placed in an array).  That was the focus of the question.  Also, Get-Command can get things other than functions (like built-in cmdlets), so that's an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

[Joey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53193211/45375) contains good information, but if all you need is to reference your functions by *name*, **define your array as containing the function names as *strings*, and invoke the functions by those strings with [`&`, the call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#call-operator-)**:

```
function Hello {  "Hello!" }

function HowAreYou { "How are you?" }

function Goodbye { "Goodbye!" }

# The array of function names *as strings*.
# Note that you don't need @(...) to create an array.
$funcs = 'Hello', 'HowAreYou', 'Goodbye'

foreach ($func in $funcs)
{
  # Use & to call the function by the name stored in a variable.
  & $func
}
```

> The issue is that the functions all run via the line that adds them to the array (ie. $scripts).

That's because your array elements are *expressions* (due to the enclosing `(...)`) that *call* the functions (e.g., `(Hello)` *calls* `Hello` and makes its *output* the array element), given that they're being referenced *without single- or double-quoting*.

Unlike in, say, `bash`, you cannot define *string* array elements as *barewords* (tokens without enclosing single- or double-quoting); for instance, the following is a *syntax error* in PowerShell:

```
# !! Does NOT work - strings must be quoted.
$funcs = Hello, HowAreYou, GoodBye # ditto with @(...)
```